# Drupal 6 Drupal_add_js

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-6

I recently realized I need to add javascript to my drupal block module for the front page. I found out that for some reason when i add:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'slider') .'/slider.js');
```

to case "view"  in slider_block function, ALL the webpages except for the front page that this module is used on, look at the .js and run it instead of loading the normal page.

the slider.js is:

```
Drupal.behaviors.slider = function(context) {

    var x
    x = 50;
    document.write (x); //prints the value of x
}
```

Comment: How do you add the js ? In which hook ?

Comment: I'm actually not sure which place to add it. Either in the _block or the _init hook. unsure!